# Get max value of binned time-interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a 'requests' table with a 'time_request' column which has a timestamp for each request. I want to know the maximum amount of requests that i had in a single minute.

So im guessing i need to somehow 'group by' a 1m time interval, and then do some sort of MAX(COUNT(request_id))? Although nested aggregations are not allowed.

Will appreciate any help.

Table example:

```
     request_id   |    time_request
------------------+---------------------
 ab1              | 2021-03-29 16:20:05
 ab2              | 2021-03-29 16:20:20
 bc3              | 2021-03-31 20:34:07
 fw3              | 2021-03-31 20:38:53
 fe4              | 2021-03-31 20:39:53
```

Expected result: 2 (There were a maximum of 2 requests in a single minute)

Thanks!

Comment: Which database are you actually using, MYSQL or POSTGRESS they are different. I removed them both, please add back only the one you are actually using

Comment: postgresql, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use window function `count` and specify logical interval of one minute as the window boundary. It will calculate the count for each row and will account all the rows that are within one minute before.

Code for Postgres is below:

> ```
> with a as (
> select
>   id
>   , cast(ts as timestamp) as ts
> from(values
>  ('ab1', '2021-03-29 16:20:05'),
>  ('ab2', '2021-03-29 16:20:20'),
>  ('bc3', '2021-03-31 20:34:07'),
>  ('fw3', '2021-03-31 20:38:53'),
>  ('fe4', '2021-03-31 20:39:53')
> ) as t(id, ts)
> )
> , count_per_interval as (
> select
>   a.*
>   , count(id) over (
>     order by ts asc
>     range between
>       interval '1' minute preceding
>       and current row
>   ) as cnt_per_min
> from a
> )
> select max(cnt_per_min)
> from count_per_interval
> ```
>
> ```
> | max |
> | --: |
> |   2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9513df762d0b364bf3ea1bf66edc525a)*